# Setting up separate ctags db's for C/C++ standard libs, boost, and third party libs

Tags: c++, c, linux, vim, ctags

I want to set up separate ctags databases for various libraries in `/usr/include/` for use with [OmniCppComplete](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C%2B%2B_code_completion).

The idea is to be able to pull in only the libraries needed for a particular project in the target language - C or C++.

For example, I'd like to have one database for the standard C libraries, one for system libraries that might be used by either C or C++ programs ( sockets / networking comes to mind ) one for the standard C++ libs / STL / Boost, and then other databases for various third party libraries such as QT or glib.  Then I could pull something in simply by typing `set tags+= ~/.vim/somelib.tags` in vim.

I assume that everything related to the C++ stdlib and STL are in the `/usr/include/c++` and that Boost is all in `/usr/include/boost`.  Unfortunately it seems that the standard C libs and system libs are just kind of dumped directly into `/usr/include/` with a variety of other stuff.

How can I get a list of which files and directories belong to which libs?  I'm on Ubuntu 8.04.

Comment: Interesting question, but maybe the title is misleading if in the end what you want is how to tell the headers apart?

Comment: Is it important to know which directories belong to which libs?

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  Yeah, primarily which files and subdir belong to the standard C library, and which ones belong to system libraries like networking.

Comment: This makes sense. If I'd read the title again, I would not have needed to ask :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[apt-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apt-file) is your friend on Ubuntu.

The following command will give you a list of all include files for Boost:

```
apt-file list -x "^libboost" | grep '/include/' | cut -f2 -d:
```

I'll leave the rest as an exercise for the reader!

**Update**: For completeness, call `apt-file update` if you have never used `apt-file` before.

Comment: I tried that on my system and the initial `apt-file list -x "^libboost"` doesn't produce any output at all.

Comment: That's odd. Was Boost installed using `apt`?

What do you get if you try `apt-file list -vx '^libstdc++`

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  I used `sudo apt-get install libboost-*` to install boost.  The command you just gave me spits out a list of deb repositories.

Comment: I'd expect to see a load of deb repositories at the beginning of the verbose [`-v`] output but then I'd expect to see a list of all the files installed as part of `libstdc++6-4.4-doc` *et al*. I'm not sure why this is not working for you, I'm afraid. I've tested this on a number of Ubuntu 10.04 installations.

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  It one of those slap yourself on the forehead moments.  First time I've ever run `apt-file` on the system.  After reading some documentation I realized that I have to run `sudo apt-file update` before I can do any searches.  Now it works.

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  ` apt-file list libc6-dev | grep '/include/' | cut -f2 -d:` works like a charm.

Comment: I'm glad you've got it working. I have updated my post for the next person to find!

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  One more tweek - `cut` puts a space at the beginning of each line of output which makes ctags barf.  Cut out `cut` and use this instead:  `apt-file list libc6-dev | grep -o '/usr/include/.*h' > ~/.vim/tags/libc6-filelist`